# Titanium iPhone Refresh function after some time

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new on titanium and iPhone development, I want to know how to auto refresh function after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval() to retrieve data from server side periodically, then setData() to render table with new data.

```
var tv = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ title:'TableView - Auto Refresh', backgroundColor:'#fff' });
    win.add(tv);
    win.open();

function fetchData() {
    var data = [];
    var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({title: 'Row ' + i});
        data.push(row);
    }
    return data;
}

function renderData() {
    tv.setData( fetchData() );
}

setInterval( renderData, 60000 );
```

Thanks